# What browser required for jquery mobile ? Can I use it with phonegap?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm just familiar with jquery for desktop and I'd like to use it also for mobile RIA. I go to provided demo site (http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/) and tried to check it out. The problem is that all browsers I have does not supports it well (buildin Android 4, chrome mobile, delphin browser - all up to date). When I explores this demo i noticed that:

- page scroll to top before transition to next one
- page blinks before transition to next one
- page opens at top when gets back to it an then scroll (visibly) to previous position, or even does not scroll at all
- listview collapse before page hide
- different browser gives different page size (fonts and controls)
- inputs does not apply styles during editing
- fixed footer twitch during content transition

My question is:
Is any browser that jquery mobile really supports... or should I rather ask, does any browser really supports jquery mobile?

I spend some time with it. I'd like to use it for my mobile RIA application. It the future I plan to transfer it to phonegap. But there is also one other problems I reached:

- using fragmented GUI looks like it works on tablet but it has the same scrolling problems and is not documented at all it this demo (here what i mean as fragments: http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png)

So the question I finally need to ask:
Is jquery mobile ready to use it for mobile RIA?

I gave it a chance because i'm using jqueru UI now any it works great. But I'm afraid to get stuck in a dead end.

Please put me some light on it if you can.

[edit]

I tested it on Samsung GT-I9100, Android 4.0.4 (I assume my users can use lower performance phones too)

Comment: What does "RIA" mean? And fact there are a lot of websites out there featuring jQuery mobile and displaying nice a broad variety of mobile browsers. I can't check those demos right now.

Comment: Rich internet applications

Comment: The way the demos are currently work is how they are intended to work. The jump to top before page transition is for performance reasons. There are ways around it, but they come with drawbacks. The blink may just be a bug related to support for the device you were testing on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser support for jQuery Mobile is listed here: http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/. It is a graded support document (A, B, and C) with each grade meaning it has a different level of support. Make sure to read the comments next to browsers carefully - it usually lists the make and model of the phone used to test it. For example, Android 4.0 browser notes that upgraded devices may have some issues.

Note that with any mobile platform, you're not just supporting the browser, you're also supporting the OS version and the hardware itself. This can make mobile development tricky, unfortunately.

Comment: I know the list. I tested it on Chrome for Android 18 (Tested on Android 4.0 and 4.1 devices) and get problems also. I'm developer and I understand some technical issues, but what to say to my users? Ask them to use special browser on special device with special OS version? This gona kill my market :(

Comment: I understand it's frustrating. You can either try to use a framework meant to standardize or test on lots of devices. Ideally both. I'd recommend something like what I linked for your own product, a graded browser support document. "It was tested in this, not in this, this OS and this phone model" etc. Ultimately you're testing three things, as I mentioned before: OS version, Hardware version, Browser version. All simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of info here:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/about/platforms.html

Yes, PhoneGap is specifically supported.

Most of the issues you detailed are limitations of mobile devices and their browsers, not jQuery Mobile. Mobile web will always provide a trade-off when compared to native apps. One gives you wide distribution with admitted limitations. The other gives you outstanding control and UI with limited cross platform options.

I am building out a sizable application with jQM. It targets enterprise type customers and for us, the distribution and cross platform capabilities far out weigh the limitations. But is all really depends on what nut your are trying to crack.

Comment: I checked list before. I have browser: Chrome for Android 18 (Tested on Android 4.0 and 4.1 devices), and it works with errors.